# matplotlib close does not close the window

Tags: python, matplotlib, conda

I have noticed that when I run:

```
import pylab as pl
pl.ion()
# Plot something
pl.show()
pl.close()
```

The last statement does not fully close the Figure. The figure goes dark, and the contents go away, but the Figure stays on the screen until I exit IPython as shown below

[image]

I am using the latest stable version of matplotlib (**1.3.1**) using an Anaconda distribution, on Linux 64 bit, and I connect remotely using `ssh -X`.

The backend I am using is below:

```
backend : QT4Agg
backend.qt4 : PySide
```

Comment: How do you create the plot? Do you use `pl.show()` (that should block the code from reaching the `pl.close` until you close the window manually). What backend do you use?

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce your problem here. What matplotlib backend are you using? I guess you are running on a linux machine connecting to a linux server?!

Comment: @DavidZwicker Just updated the OP. Yes, I connect from a Linux box to a Linux server where I run the code.

Comment: Hmm looks like a normal setup to me. Have you tried switching to another backend like `TkAgg`? As I said I can't reproduce your problem, but it looks like a bug to me.

Comment: And to confirm, you are using this interactively in an ipython shell?  If so this looks like a bug to me, if you are running this as a script, I am not surprised there is something funny with eventloops getting started/not started in pyplot when running in a script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to specify wich figure you want to close. In case you want to close all of them:

```
pl.close('all')
```

Also, there is a way to just clear but not close a figure:

```
pl.clf()
```

Also, seen below from [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140787/closing-pyplot-windows):

> Remember that `plt.show()` is a blocking function, so in the example code you used above, `plt.close()` isn't being executed until the window is closed, which makes it redundant.
>
> You can use `plt.ion()` at the beginning of your code to make it non-blocking, although this has other implications.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following lines after your plotting

```
#Your Plotting function
plt.waitforbuttonpress(0) 
plt.close(fig)
```

The `plt.waitforbuttonpress(0)`  will wait until a user input (Key press) is given. After that it will properly close the matplotlib window properly. It is very important to specify which figure to close.