# How to clear the cache in Matplotlib for python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to create lots of figures, then use `savefig` to save the figure.

But after about 280 pictures, it throws the exception `RuntimeError: Could not allocate memory for image`

Is there some function like `clear()` in Matplotlib ?

Comment: Reassign any variables referring to your pictures and Python should clear the memory for you.

Comment: Are you using a single figure object or creating many figures?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matplotlib runs out of memory when plotting in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364945/matplotlib-runs-out-of-memory-when-plotting-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use:

- `clf()`: in order to [clean the current figure](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.clf)
- `close()`: in order to [close the current window](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.close)

Comment: dont forget https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401057/matplotlib-close-does-not-close-the-window : see were it says : Remember that plt.show() is a blocking function, so in the example code you used above, plt.close() isn't being executed until the window is closed, which makes it redundant.

You can use plt.ion() at the beginning of your code to make it non-blocking, although this has other implications.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
i=1
while i<=280:
    plt.figure(i).clear()
    i+=1
```

But you have to numbered your figures:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *

# example of data:
x = linspace(0,4,1e3)
data = sin(10*x)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x, data)
plt.show()
```