# Matplotlib close plot/figure automatically after viewing

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

So I got a small problem, but yeah, I need an answer. A created a plot with matplotlib, and after the showing I want to close it. 
Of course, I visited some documentation (e.g.: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.close.html), a lot of forums, like that: [matplotlib close does not close the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401057/matplotlib-close-does-not-close-the-window), but my code isn't working for me.

I used the `plt.ion()` function, but when I tryed it, the plot wasn't appearing, I just saw an empty window.
After that, I used the `plt.show(block = False)` and I again got an empty window.

You can see the code above:

```py
#Showing

plt.ion()
plt.show(block = False)

time.sleep(10)

plt.close("all")
```

As you can see, there's a delay, I would like to see a plot for ten seconds, and after close it.

Feel free, to comment to me, I appreciate that, thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Do not use `time.sleep()`. Use the `plt.pause()` function.**

---

**Details/Explanation**: **First**, you need `plt.show(block=False)` so that the plot is not blocked and the code executes the next command.

**Second**, the second command i.e. `plt.pause(3)` pauses the plot for 3 seconds and then goes to the next line/command.

**Finally**, the last line/command, `plt.close("all")` closes the plot automatically.

---

This is a script (`.py`) that plots an `imshow` and automatically close it after 3 seconds.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(10,10)

plt.imshow(X)

plt.show(block=False)
plt.pause(3) # 3 seconds, I use 1 usually
plt.close("all")
```