matplotlib.pyplot not closing window on Mac
matplotlib is not closing its window screen after disposal of plot. It is still running on background.
    # python code
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(getXData(), getYData(), label="Line 1")
    plt.savefig("plot.png", bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.clf()
    plt.close("all")
    ...
    ...
    # long code that will run for hours 


matplotlib running after closing
The question here is different - I followed the accepted answer that is not working in my case. The issue is completely different as my window is distoyed and showing only icon on taskbar.
Can you suggest me what changes need to do in code, to completely close the window.
This issue might exist on MacBook only

s/plt.close()/plt.close(fig)/

The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401057/matplotlib-close-does-not-close-the-window is different - I followed the accepted answer that is not working in my case. The issue is completely different as my window is distoyed and showing only icon on taskbar.

This is funny: if I execute your code on different platforms I see no icon at all.

Every operating system works in different way. The icon in mac signify that the particular application is running. In linux you can check using top command. I found this bug in MacOS and not able to recreate in different OS. That's why I already mentioned the issue might only exist on MacOS binary.
