# Callbacks for graphical mouse input - how to refresh graphics, how to tell Matplotlib I am done?

Tags: python, class, matplotlib, callback

Hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong in my first program using
callbacks.

The goal:

- Show a plot containing data
- Allow the user to click on the plot 4 times. Each time, the X-coordinate
     is appended to a saved list.
- While the mouse is moving, its horizontal location is tracked by a vertical
     line that moves back and forth within the plot. (I save the 2D line
     object as `self.currentLine`)
- When user selects a point by clicking, the vertical line is dropped at the
     x-coordinate of interest, and a new one is generated to continue tracking
     mouse position.

At the end of user input, there should be four vertical lines and the class
should return a list containing their x-coordinates.

At present, I can't figure out the proper way to update the line objects in
the plot (i.e. so I can get the mouse tracking effect I want). I also can't get
the class to return the list of values when finished.

I know the `while` loop probably isn't the right approach, but I can't figure out the proper one.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pdb

class getBval:
    def __init__(self):
        figWH = (8,5) # in
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=figWH)
        plt.plot(range(10),range(10),'k--')
        self.ax = self.fig.get_axes()[0]
        self.x = [] # will contain 4 "x" values
        self.lines = [] # will contain 2D line objects for each of 4 lines            

        self.connect =    self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect
        self.disconnect = self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect

        self.mouseMoveCid = self.connect("motion_notify_event",self.updateCurrentLine)
        self.clickCid     = self.connect("button_press_event",self.onClick)
    def updateCurrentLine(self,event):
        xx = [event.xdata]*2
        self.currentLine, = self.ax.plot(xx,self.ax.get_ylim(),'k')
        plt.show()
    def onClick(self, event):
        if event.inaxes:
            self.updateCurrentLine(event)
            self.x.append(event.xdata)
            self.lines.append(self.currentLine)
            del self.currentLine
            if len(self.x)==4:
                self.cleanup()
    def cleanup(self):
        self.disconnect(self.mouseMoveCid)
        self.disconnect(self.clickCid)
        return self


xvals = getBval()
print xvals.x
```

Comment: Due to the way that call backs work you can't get a 'return' pre-say but you can ask the object if a) it is done and b) what it's values are.  Event driven programming can take a bit of time to get your head around.

Comment: Thanks. If a `return` statement isn't appropriate, what is the accepted protocol for waiting until the object is done? Just a `while` loop that repeatedly checks the value of a variable until it meets criteria (e.g. a list of 4 items in my problem)? This seems inefficient, but I don't know what to google for to find the right answer. Thanks again.

Comment: `signals` can be handy or just while + sleep (assuming you have threads).  With what you are doing you might want to give up on a simple script and embrace the gui frame work you are using (embedding mpl) which would give you more call backs you can trigger when enough points are selceted.

Comment: _assuming you have threads_ Sleep + while prevents window from showing up at all (maybe this should tell me I don't have threads). Do you mean I need to import & use `threading` module? Also, by embedding mpl, do you mean [like this? (tkinter)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140787/closing-pyplot-windows) (partly addresses issues I am having now)

Comment: no, embedding like this: http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a `Cursor` widget for your vertical line, and just collect the x values of the clicks (not the entire `Line2D`), here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.widgets as mwidgets

class getBval:

    def __init__(self):
        figWH = (8,5) # in
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=figWH)
        plt.plot(range(10),range(10),'k--')
        self.ax = self.fig.get_axes()[0]
        self.x = [] # will contain 4 "x" values
        self.lines = [] # will contain 2D line objects for each of 4 lines            

        self.cursor = mwidgets.Cursor(self.ax, useblit=True, color='k')
        self.cursor.horizOn = False

        self.connect = self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect
        self.disconnect = self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect

        self.clickCid = self.connect("button_press_event",self.onClick)

    def onClick(self, event):
        if event.inaxes:
            self.x.append(event.xdata)
            if len(self.x)==4:
                self.cleanup()

    def cleanup(self):
        self.disconnect(self.clickCid)
        plt.close()


xvals = getBval()
plt.show()

print xvals.x
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about mpl 'Widgets'--these look useful. I guess I didn't phrase my question well, but one obstacle I am having is not knowing how to control flow of my program---I want it to wait for user input, and then once fourth item is saved to list, continue to next part of program and use that data elsewhere. Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: Well, the combination `plt.show()` and the just added `plt.close()` on `cleanup` should do what you want (check the code of my answer), though not the better approach (at least from the OOP point of view)

Comment: `plt.close` doesn't work with `plot.show()` ([see relevant post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140787/closing-pyplot-windows))---but using `draw()` doesn't seem to work either so long as program flow is continuing. This includes `sleep` as @tcaswell indicated above. I am reluctant to learn tkinter just for this task, because I wouldn't expect to use it much (PhD student; this is just a hack for me to rapidly process some test data). Hmmm. Stumped for now! Thanks again.

Comment: Did you run my code and `plt.close()` didn't  close the window?... I've just copy-pasted the code today and it runs smoothly, it even prints the list of x values as the final statement says. But my back-end is PyQt maybe it has something to do