# Python: close the figure window and let the program go

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a python program, say, `train.py`. It can be run in anaconda prompt by typing:

```
python train.py
```

In `train.py`, some part is written for drawing and saving figures:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
....... #I omit these codes
plt.savefig(....)
plt.show() #this will produce a figure window 
plt.close()
```

In implementing the program, some figures are to be generated, which will bring the program to a temporary halt, even though `plt.close()` present. Then I need to manually close the pop-up figure window due to `plt.show()` and continue the program. How to avoid this inconvenience.

It is noted that `spyder` can run the program continuously, with figures displayed in its console.

Comment: Is there a reason you would use `plt.show()` to be immediately followed by an attempt to close that window?

Comment: I still want to see these figures, and then they are closed by coding

Comment: Have you read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140787/closing-pyplot-windows)? Did it help?

Comment: Do you want the figures to be displayed for a certain time period, say 10 seconds, and then the windows be closed?

Answer (score 1):

`plt.show()` is meant to be used once in a script to show all figures present. So you can create your figures and show them all at the end

```
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
# do something with figure 1

fig2 = plt.figure(2)
# do something with figure 2

plt.show() # show both figures
```