# How to plot and save separate plots using matplot lib and python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot 6 different plots on matplot lib and save them each to a folder. However, it looks like they are all plotting on top of each other, so the first saved image is correct, but the second is just the second plot on top of the first plot. I would like the second plot, and all following, to just be that plot, not on top of the previous one. This is the code I have used, thank you so much!

```
for x in range(len(sizeDict)):
    plt.plot(xAxis,sizeDict[x])
    plt.title('size'+str(x))
    plt.savefig("/Users/name/Desktop/Work/Size"+ str(x) + ".png")

for x in range(len(shapeDict)):
    plt.plot(xAxis,shapeDict[x])
    plt.title('shape'+str(x))
    plt.savefig("/Users/Name/Desktop/Work/Shape"+ str(x) + ".png")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closing pyplot windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140787/closing-pyplot-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either create another figure or close the current one. You can use `plt.figure()` to create a new one or `plt.close()` to close the current one.